# How to programmatically set `ContentControl.Content` as the dependency property for a data binding between a Button and a string property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to create a simple data binding programmatically in a minimal WPF application. The source is the `SourceText` property in the `SourceClass` instance and the target is the `Button` control:

XAML File:

```
namespace notify_on_source_updated
{

    public class SourceClass
    {
        public string SourceText { get; set; } 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Binding binding = new Binding("SourceText");

            binding.Source = new SourceClass() { SourceText = "test" };
            binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true;
            
            btnAddInt.SetBinding(ContentControl.Content, binding);
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this I get an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ContentControl.Content'

As far as I can tell the `ContentControl.Content` is the correct dependency property here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "ContentControl.Content is the correct dependency property" - it is not a DependencyProperty at all

Comment: Be aware that setting NotifyOnSourceUpdated makes no sense without alos subscribing to the SourceUpdated event.

Comment: Content is of course a dependency property. Its identifier field is ContentProperty, which must be passed to SetBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be Content**Property**:

```
btnAddInt.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Strange that this is not documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: It's documented under the Fields section.

Comment: It is the Identifier field. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.